# How to get all the A_Args[] element that could potential be sent in from a CLI/Terminal?

Tags: autohotkey

Lets say I have a `.ahk` file like the following:

```
msgbox % A_args
Array := [A_Args[1], A_Args[2], A_Args[2], A_Args[3], A_Args[4], A_Args[5]]  

For each, Element in Array {
    FileAppend, %Element% `n , C:\temp\Test.txt
}
```

and from the terminal I want to start the script with  one or more items:

```
.\Test.ahk "One" "Two" "Three"
```

Inside the AHK script, how can I get all the items sent in at once, rather than one at a time with `A_Args[1]`, `A_Args[2]` etc etc. The following works for 5 items:

```
Array := [A_Args[1], A_Args[2], A_Args[2], A_Args[3], A_Args[4], A_Args[5]]
```

But its sub optimal, what If I am only sending in 3 items or in another instance 73 items?
Amonst the things I tried are: `msgbox % A_args` but this prints empty

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm sorry but this question doesn't really make sense to me. Why are you doing `Array := [A_Args[1], A_Args[2], A_Args[2], A_Args[3], A_Args[4], A_Args[5]]`?

Comment: `Array := [A_Args[1], A_Args[2], A_Args[2], A_Args[3], A_Args[4], A_Args[5]]` is just a inneficient way I came up with to collect all the arguments sent in from the command line so that I can use `Array` in a loop. I am looking for a way that will save me from the doing this. As there can be 10 or 100 arguments coming  in from the command line and mannually collecting them with `Array := [A_Args[1], A_Args[2]]...` is not feasable. I hope that explains it :)

Comment: `A_Args` is an array, just loop through it.

Comment: I just checked to confirm. A_Args is just a variable! Since its not something I myself created, I just assumed it was one of those special AHK facilities that the user has to store somewhere. Thanks!